# Preventing Http Redirect 307 with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am connecting to a WCF Service that does a re-direct to another Url.

When I connect to the WCF Service at http://myserver-hp/testws. This in turn does a re-direct to the end point : http://rootserver:8000/sampleservice/sampleservice.svc.  For the re-direct, I ceated a virtual directory in IIS and then used Http Redirect available in Features View.

From the client I want to return an error when the server is doing a redirect. I tried adding a custom IEndpointBehavior and IClientMessageInspector. But then I am unable to detect the Http 307 ..

Is there any way for the WCF client to detect the fact the server is doing a Http Redirect to another Url. I am using wsHttpBinding in the WCF service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client can check the http status code,which will be 307, to decide the redirect.

If you are working with SOAP, you should use routing services.

WCF does auto redirect, if endpoint name matches with "/". It adds that to the end. This happens if you specify various method calls under the same endpoint without method name in uritemplates. It will match the proper call based on method type, like "GET","PUT" for all empty uritemplates.